# Rails many-to-many :through association: associated object is not updated after destroying the association object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, has-many

As I am new to Rails, there is may be a trivial solution. But I could not even find this exact issue somewhere. Other posts deal with destroy vs. delete (I tried both with the same result) or just do not mention how the associated object behaves.

My problem: I want to create a many-to-many association via :through. When I delete an association (i.e. the relation object, not the related objects) I expect that this association is removed (updated) in all model instances of the associated objects. But this does not fully happen.

My example:

```
Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations
  has_many :users, :through => :participations

User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations
  has_many :meetings, :through => :participations

Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :meeting, :foreign_key => :meeting_id
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :user_id
```

When I create a new association, the associated objects are updated accordingly:

```
u = User.find(...)
m = Meeting.find(...)
m.users<< u
```

The same when creating the association this way:

```
m.participations.create(:user_id => u.id)  # this requires to make the user_id attribute accessible
```

When I now look at the associated user model instance, it got updated as expected:

```
u.meetings >> contains the newly created association to the meeting m
```

When I destroy (not delete!) this association, the associated object is not updated as I expect it:

```
m.users.find_by_user_id(u.id).destroy
m.users >> []
u.meetings >> still contains the destroyed association to meeting m
```

I would have expected that u.meetings is updated and empty ([]). Adding validations didn't help to solve this:

```
Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_associated :contacts
or
Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :contact, :interview
```

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing here?

I am using Rails 3.2.8

Thanks to everyone who is willing to help me.

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing `:dependent => :destroy`.

```
Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :participations

User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :meetings, :through => :participations

Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :meeting, :foreign_key => :meeting_id
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :user_id
```

This will make sure to destroy the `participation` if either of the associated user or meeting is destroyed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention it. But I tried that, too. I also checked all callbacks and participation.before_destroy and participation.after_destroy were triggered. But still, if I call u.meetings it is not empty as expected. It still contains the just destroyed association. It is deleted within the db but not removed from the meetings enumeration of the u instance.

Comment: I think you are looking at the cached data then. Try doing `u.reload` and then try `u.meetings`.

Comment: Ok, thank you a lot. Both approaches `u.reload` and `u.meetings(true)` work as expected and do refresh the (previously instantiated) user object `u`. Just to learn about Rails: why is the `u` instance being updated after the association was created but not after it was destroyed. Is there any meaningful reason? This way, I always have to refresh instances to make sure not to show outdated information.

Answer (score 1):

You should update your `model` with the following relationship option:

```
dependent: destroy
```

Which will call `destroy` on the associated objects.

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Deleting+from+associations

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem could be like this. In your example,

```
m.users.find_by_user_id(u.id).destroy
m.users >> []
u.meetings >> still contains the destroyed association to meeting m
```

`u` and `u.meetings` were already loaded before `m.users.find_by_user_id(u.id).destroy`. Then `u.meetings` output the cached data.

You can try `u.meetings(true)` or `u.reload; u.meetings` to see if there are any difference.